# Error handling for MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

Instead of sending queries to PHPs `mysql_query()` function I currently send my queries to a custom wrapper sql_query(), which, amongst other things does the "mysql_query" part.

The problem with this setup is that when there's an SQL error the file and the line number are where the sql_query() function is located, rather then where the actual SQL query is.

Is there a way of having PHP report the file and linenumber of where sql_query() is called from, rather than where the `mysql_query()` function actually is?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MySQL. It's about obtaining debugging information from a function call heirarchy.

Comment: I don't want to be a pain: but why was my question downvoted?

Comment: I was considering it originally, as you provide no code and no indication of what you're _really_ doing other than in prose (most of which talks about SQL, which is not relevant to the question at all). I did manage to find the thinly veiled request underneath it, though. It's just not very well-stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

And many helpful example there for your problem. One of this.
Surprisingly, no one has described one of the best uses of this: dumping a variable and showing the location. When debugging, especially a big and unfamiliar system, it's a pain remembering where I added those var dumps. Also, this way there is a separator between multiple dump calls.

```
<?php

function dump( $var ) {
     $result = var_export( $var, true );
     $loc = whereCalled();
     return "\n<pre>Dump: $loc\n$result</pre>";
 }

 function whereCalled( $level = 1 ) {
     $trace = debug_backtrace();
     $file   = $trace[$level]['file'];
     $line   = $trace[$level]['line'];
     $object = $trace[$level]['object'];
     if (is_object($object)) { $object = get_class($object); }

     return "Where called: line $line of $object \n(in $file)";
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the stack trace. It's usually in the error context, otherwise you can use libraries like [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) to fetch one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass this information to the wrapper using `__FILE__ and __LINE__` constants.

Answer (score -1):

You should add some error-handling to your sql_query(). You could check this functions:

[mysql_errno](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php) and [mysql_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) and in case of you have any error raise an exception.

Comment: You forgot to read the question thoroughly enough to see past the red herring!

Comment: I read the question. And my Answer can be extended to any situation where in a helper class/library you check for an error and raise a custom exception. It's called object oriented design. And you can find patterns that do this. I prefer a well designed system than a self-error-thrower one.

Comment: No, you misunderstood it. The question is "how do I fix my error handling?" Your answer is "use error handling". Also, objects and exceptions are largely orthogonal.